# Switch to WSL and execute a command in one line in PowerShell not working

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, powershell-3.0

I want to write a function that opens WSL in PowerShell and executes these commands:

```
HOSTIP=`cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | cut -b 12-`
cd /tmp; mkfifo pip; nc -l -p 12345 < pip | nc ${HOSTIP} 12345 > pip
```

I tried:

```
wsl -e sh -c "HOSTIP=\$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | cut -b 12-); cd /tmp; mkfifo pip; nc -l -p 12345 < pip | nc \${HOSTIP} 12345 > pip"
```

... but it does not execute and gives the error `cut is not recognised`.

Is this the right way to execute the command in WSL in PowerShell?

Comment: Does the command work if you just run it in an interactive wsl session? This *probably* isn’t directly a Powershell issue - your wsl system *maybe* needs some tools (specifically ```cut```) added to it… then again my knowledge of wsl is very limited, but confirming if the command works interactively will help diagnose your problem either way…

Comment: Try single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a few suggestions for the question itself that will ultimately (hopefully) help answer it:

- It's best to create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE) of the problem.  What's the shortest command-line that demonstrates the issue?  It's always *possible* that there are other issues later in your script, and we need to focus on one at a time:

  In this case, to focus in the issue in your question, let's go with:

  ```
  wsl -e sh -c "HOSTIP=\$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | cut -b 12-)"
  ```

  That should reproduce your error.  That also makes it easier to troubleshoot.  For good measure, you could throw in an `echo` to return the result:

  ```
  wsl -e sh -c "HOSTIP=\$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | cut -b 12-); echo \$HOSTIP"
  ```

  You *might* also have spotted the problem in that case, since the `HOSTIP` would appear highlighted as a PowerShell variable.
- Second, make sure you provide the exact error message.  This would have made it easier for others to spot the issue.  I'm assuming that it was:

  ```
  cut: The term 'cut' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
  Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
  ```

  This tells use that PowerShell is interpreting at least part of your commandline that you are intending for `sh`.  If the issue were *inside* WSL, the error would have been something along the line of:

  ```
  sh: 1: cut: not found
  ```

##### *Short answer (non-optimal)*:

As mentioned in the comments, it's better if you use single quotes here.  You'll also need to remove the `\` escape symbol:

```
wsl -e sh -c 'HOSTIP=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | cut -b 12-); echo $HOSTIP'
```

##### *Alternative #1*:

You could properly escape the dollar-sign with the backtick `` ` ``:

```
wsl -e sh -c "HOSTIP=`$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | cut -b 12-); echo `$HOSTIP"
```

##### *Alternative #2 (**Preferred**)*:

When passing in multiple commands, *especially* with more complicated quoting/escaping situations, I'd recommend just going ahead and create a script  in WSL that you would run from PowerShell:

```
wsl -e /home/<username>/.local/bin/scriptfile.sh
```

Note that your script should start with a proper shebang line for this to work.

##### *Alternative #3:*

When working with multiple commands, consider passing them in with linebreaks using a PowerShell multiline string (as opposed to semicolons) for readability:

```
wsl -e sh -c @'
    HOSTIP=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | cut -b 12-)
    cd /tmp
    mkfifo pip
    nc -l -p 12345 < pip | nc ${HOSTIP} 12345 > pip
'@
```